# Sending signed transactions

Tags: web3js

I want to call an action on a contract that is deployed on rinkeby test net. But transaction confirmation seems to take forever and I can't find it on rinkeby etherscan. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
let Web3= require('web3');
let web3 = new Web3 (new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

tokenAbi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"supplyLimit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"addr","type":"address"},{"name":"unlockTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"lockTill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"transfersAreLocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"locked","type":"bool"}],"name":"changeTransferLock","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"previousOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipRenounced","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]

const tokenAddress = '0xAfff042F602762B59442660aCDF34fdE8681D016';
var Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenAbi, tokenAddress, {from: '0x6C7bc8e30cAE5409b30c16eFA458eADAaE6e6810'});
const tokenReceiver = '0x426e238593d7969f1beb174287a367dd9f41362F';
const tokenAmount = '100000000000000000000';
const PK = 'cdfa2d70c2f309106665188dc69996e3150983737b4b0882b768b11221d8a603'

const trxData = Contract.methods.transfer(tokenReceiver, tokenAmount).encodeABI();

web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x6C7bc8e30cAE5409b30c16eFA458eADAaE6e6810').then(function(nonce){

  var rawTx = {
  to: '0xafff042f602762b59442660acdf34fde8681d016',
  data: trxData,
  gasPrice: 1000000000,
  gasLimit: 7000000,
  nonce: nonce,
  chainId: 4
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
const privateKey = Buffer.from(PK, 'hex')
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
.on('receipt', console.log);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, gs limit of 100 is too low. Transaction might not be getting picked-up up for inclusion on pending block.

Try increasing the gas limit.

Comment: I have made tx limit 999. If I make it over 999 I get 'exceeds block limit' error. Altho   rinkeby gas limit is 7119155. Is it something wrong here?

Comment: 1. What is the Transaction hash that you get after submitting transaction ? 
2. Do you increment nonce for each transaction ?

Comment: transaction hash `0x65986d6a4df8e4b8c38977795d87b82b3089c60d7ba7183c9c8768963c927efe` I can't find it on the Rinkeby network. And yes, I do increment it, because otherwise, it gives me an error.

Comment: Do you have a local node ? Does that node provide any info? (Like eth.getTransaction(txHash) on geth console .

Comment: Yes, I have a local node. And yes node provides information about the submitted transaction with transaction hash.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with my web3 module. I am using version 1.0.0-beta.36

Answer (score 0):

The `gasPrice` is too low, try: 2000000000 (2Gwei)
The `gasLimit` is too low, is even lower than the base price for a transaction, try increasing it (remember that the non-used gas is returned to you)

The nonce should be updated after every transaction, use:

`web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, still the same problem. Transaction takes forever to execute and I can't find it on rinkeby block explorer. Here is my updated code: '   var rawTx = {
  to: '0xafff042f602762b59442660acdf34fde8681d016',
  data: trxData,
  gasPrice: 2000000000,
  gasLimit: 7000000,
  nonce: nonce
} '

Comment: can you please update the question with your new code?, also can you share the hash of the transaction that is taking forever?

Comment: Updated the code above

Comment: Your nonce is still incorrect, why are you adding 2 to the value returned by the function? The transaction has a nonce that is above the current one, and will not be processed until the missing values are observed in the network.

Comment: Updated the code and used different account. But problem remains still

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem was that there were too many stuck transactions in the tx pool, so I had to clean them by turning my node off and deleting `transactions.rlp` file